# Why do apps not emphasise on 'Login' buttons like they do for 'Sign up' buttons?

Tags: login, signup-signon, discovery, visibility

[image]

There are few obvious reasons for a prominent sign up buttons like,

1. We need more signups
2. We need the visitors to locate the sign up button quickly
3. Most of the apps, dont sign out users after they leave the app. We are auto-signed in when we come back to that app. Like Facebook, google does.

But my concern is, what if I am using a different system or browser. In that case, it takes a moment to locate these login buttons/links.

Some apps(mobile and desktop), even have login as links that are difficult to click (with less touch area).

Doesnt Login buttons deserve better ? Atleast a ghost button like the below screenshot ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's not a good practice to highlight too many elements since users might find it hard to get to the primary function.

I think that's why designers focus on the most important one which is to cater new / registering users by highlighting the most important function to them.

This being said, I also agree on your point that needs to be a little prominent since its the second important thing after a sign up, so if it was me i would be at least putting a up a grey box around the login button (in your screenshot) to give a similar button feel to both login and signup and keep the sign up button blue colored so it stands out as the primary function.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is in your question.

Sign up is most important for visitors to the app that are new to the ui.

Returning visitors who are mostly likely to have already been through sign up will be already logged in and then won't see it again unless they actively decide to log out. Also they are more familiar with the ui and something similar to banner blindness would apply here where they unconsciously ignore the sign up button regardless of how prominent it is.

Answer (score 0):

Signup has more priority than Signin. Once a user has signed up, he knows the exact position on the page from where he can sign in.

> what if I am using a different system or browser

By design, login/signin button is always on the top on 95% apps. What do you mean by different browser's. I assume layout would be same.

Answer (score 0):

As was said before, you can't highlight everything, so you need to choose what will be most important to highlight.

The highlighted signup button is a hook, meant to catch passing fish (a.k.a users). Those don't have a lot of time or patience for the page ahead, and in 8 seconds tops you're going to lose them. So a large and emphasized button is needed.

Already registered users are a different matter whatsoever. They have more patience - by already registering they kind of say "We trust you". They most probably arrived to this page to do stuff, not to run away. So they will look for that link.

That being said - the sign in button isn't that hidden, after all it resides near the large Signup button. Once the eye will move to that area, it will be a matter of a second of two before the sign in is discovered.